# Firebird ADO.NET issue with loading a Dataset from the FbDataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, firebird, dataadapter

I have several freely available data access layers on my business site. I have always followed the Firebird database on their site and have now decided to build a new data access layer for this database engine.

I am using the ADO.NET provider recommended on the Firebird site (https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/). The version being used is 5.5.

I have developed a simple stored procedure to process returning several columns of data, which has been tested successfully in my database manager. It has also been tested successfully with the data-reader within the test-client I am building for my Firebird data access layer.

However, when I attempt to test the stored-procedure against the return of a dataset, I consistently receive the following error...

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Even a simple inline query with a parameter yields the same error.

Yet these very same tests work fine with my data-reader processes.

This error is always yielded when it comes to my code in the process that "fills" a dataset from the Firebird data-adapter.

The code I am testing is below

```
Public Overloads Function ExecuteDataSet(ByVal psConnectionString As String, _
                                         ByVal psQuery As String, _
                                         ByRef poParameterStructures As ArrayList) As DataSet

    Dim loParameterStructures  As New ArrayList()

    Dim loDataSet                As DataSet
    Dim loFbSqlConnection        As FbConnection = Nothing
    Dim loFbSqlParameter         As FbParameter
    Dim loFbSqlCommand           As FbCommand = Nothing
    Dim loFbSqlDataAdapter       As FbDataAdapter = Nothing


    Try 
        'DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        'FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("select_mytable", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString);
        'da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        'da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", 123);
        'da.Fill(dt);

        loFbSqlConnection = Get_DBConnection(psConnectionString)

            loFbSqlCommand = New FbCommand(psQuery, loFbSqlConnection)
            loFbSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = ciTimeOut

            ' check for parameterized inline SQL or stored-procedure
            If ((psQuery.IndexOf("@") > -1) Or _
                (psQuery.ToUpper().IndexOf("SELECT ") > -1)) Then
                loFbSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Else        
                loFbSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure      
            End If  


            ' create parameters for stored-procedure
            If (Not poParameterStructures Is Nothing) Then
                For Each loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure As FbSqlHelperParameterStructure In poParameterStructures
                    loFbSqlParameter = New FbParameter() 

                        loFbSqlParameter.ParameterName = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_NAME
                        loFbSqlParameter.DbType = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_FBSQLDBTYPE
                        loFbSqlParameter.Direction = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_DIRECTION

                        Select Case loFbSqlParameter.Direction  
                            Case ParameterDirection.Input:
                                loFbSqlParameter.Value = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_VALUE
                                loFbSqlParameter.Size = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_SIZE

                            Case ParameterDirection.Output:
                                loFbSqlParameter.Size = loFbSqlHelperParameterStructure.PARAMETER_SIZE
                        End Select

                    loFbSqlCommand.Parameters.Add(loFbSqlParameter)
                Next
            End If

        loFbSqlDataAdapter = New FbDataAdapter()                
        loFbSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = loFbSqlCommand

        loDataSet = New DataSet()
        loFbSqlDataAdapter.Fill(loDataSet)
    Catch loFbSqlException As FbException
        Throw loFbSqlException
    Catch loException As Exception
        Throw loException
    Finally
        loFbSqlCommand.Dispose()
        loFbSqlConnection.Close()
        loFbSqlConnection.Dispose()
    End Try


    poParameterStructures = loParameterStructures

    Return (loDataSet)
End Function
```

The code above has also been successfully used with my other data access layers that support SQL Server, SQL Server CE, MySQL, and PostgreSQL.

However, in the case of the Firebird database, no matter what code-setup from the all of the documentation I have gone through on acquiring a data-set from the Firebird database yields exactly the same error noted above. Thus the code provided here is the original code that is used successfully in my other data access layers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem with the code above...

If you look in my "Finally" statement you will see the following line of code...  "loFbSqlCommand.Dispose()"

Though, this line of code has been used successfully in other data access layers I distribute, for the Firebird ADO.NET data provider it breaks a chain of reference pointers up into the returned dataset, which is a completely separate object from the FbDataAdapter.

Remove this line of code or comment it out and the code works fine.

Comment: Could you file a bug for that on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET, because that doesn't sound like something that should happen.